# Xpath selecting the second element

Tags: html, xpath

I am having issues with selecting the 2nd element while doing some automation work.
Apologies for being unable to provide the actual document.

There are 2 duplicate elements found in Chrome console: the first one is invisible until I clicked somewhere and there will be additional attributes that will appear in the second element which I am unable to access, until the link I am supposed to click is detected but the automation is unable to.

here is the relative path:
//div[@id=tab_main"]/nav/div/a[2]

absolute path for 1st element: /html/body/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/nav/div/a[2]

absolute path for 2nd element: /html/body/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/nav/div/a[2]

I have tried countless ways, such as using last(), or [2] but am still unable to reliably find the second element.

Any pointers or tips are deeply appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide debugging details we can only guess.
So, I guess this should work:

```
'(//div[@id="tab_main"]/nav/div/a)[2]'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding i attempted this xpath you provided and I am still getting both results within Chrome console. Any other information you require to help solve this? I will try to provide the source in abit

Comment: If you can provide the entire XML / HTML as a text it can be useful to make some debugging

Comment: This XPath (like the one in KJ Huang's question) is invalid as it contains an unmatched `"` character. Maybe `(//div[@id='tab_main']/nav/div/a)[2]` would work?

Comment: @KJHuang can you check the fixed version?